# find a number p such that the number $(2)(3)(5)(7)...(p) + 1$ is not prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

find a prime number p such that the number $(2)(3)(5)(7)...(p) + 1$ is not prime.

attempt:

let n be the non prime number. therefore:

$$(2)(3)(5)(7)...(p) + 1 = n $$

but n is not prime so it is composite.  Let $n = 2k$ . Therefore

$$p = \frac{2k - 1}{(2)(3)(5)(7)...}$$

I did this because they did not specify what the non prime had to be so i gave a shot in the dark with $2k$

thoughts?

Comment: Are you familiar with the proof of infinitude of primes?

Comment: I am familiar with it yes. and LMAO on the user name, but what does it do here?

Comment: @dc3rd: $n=2k$ is not a good choice since $(2)(3)\cdots(p)+1$ is always odd.

Comment: Your $n$ is clearly odd

Comment: $n = (2)(3)(5)(7)\cdots(p) + 1$ implies that $n$ is odd, which means it is not possible that $n = 2k$. If $n$ exists, you know that $n = 2k + 1$ for some $k$, in fact $k = (3)(5)(7)\cdots(p)$, but this still gives us no clue as to how large $p$ should be.

Comment: Sorry about that I didn't see that $p$ was prime in this instance.

Comment: On a side note, primes of such forms are called Primorial Primes (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial_prime)

Answer (score 4):

$$59 \mid 30031 = 2\cdots13 + 1$$

Answer (score 2):

Just because a number isn't prime does not mean it has to be even. In fact, any number in the form $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots p+1$ will be odd, as it is one more than a multiple of $2$. So, your assumption that $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots p_n+1 = 2k$ for some integer $k$ is false.

Fortunately, for this problem, it doesn't take long to test the first few numbers of that form and find one which isn't prime:

$2+1 = 3$ (prime)

$2 \cdot 3 + 1 = 7$ (prime)

$2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 + 1 = 31$ (prime)

$2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7+ 1 = 211$ (prime)

$2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11+ 1 = 2311$ (prime)

$2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 + 1 = 30031 = 59 \cdot 509$ (not prime)

Therefore, one such $p$ is $p = 13$.

Comment: How I interpreted the question was that they were not asking for a specific example, but a generalized form so that is what led me to what I attempted. I guess my interpretation was wrong and they truly just wanted a concrete number. By chance is there a generalized form? Or would it be cases?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you want to generalize $n$, you have to write $n = m k$ for some integers $m$, $k$, not $n = 2k$.